# Windows Forms DataGridView Changing Single Row Colour Causes All Rows To Change

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a standard windows form datagridview. Within it I am setting the data from a linq created list. I want to conditionally format the rows based on the value of the DataBoundItem from each row. I have looked up how to do it from previous stackoverflow threads and there is multiple solutions based around the following:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridViewSelect.Rows)
{
    if (property.GetValue(row.DataBoundItem, null) != highlightOptions.Value)
    {
        row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
        row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;
    }
    else
    {
        row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
        row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Black;
    }
}
```

I have tried putting this code under the cell formatting event and after binding the data. Wherever I put it all rows get formatted Red despite the fact when running through the code only a few cells fire the Red formatting.

Comment: In CellFormatting event you don't need to use a loop. Just format the row which the event is raised for.

Comment: Also to check a criteria based on `DataBoundItem` of the row, you don't need to use reflection.For example if `DataBoundItem` is of type of `Product`, you can simply use `((Product)row.DataBoundItem).Price` for example.

Comment: This is from a custom user control for selecting data, the options for highlighting rows are based on strings so the field being highlighted is not known until runtime.

Comment: In case which you said, it's OK to use reflection. Also if you are sure the column is present in `DataGridView`, you can get the `Column`from the user (at design-time) and simply use value of the column at run-time.